# Simpler proof of the lemma: if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then all odd factor of $a^2 + 3b^2$ has the same form?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Lemma: If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then every odd factor of $a^2 + 3b^2$ has this same form.

I was reviewing the proofs for this lemma online. Every proof is long and cumbersome. Is there a simpler method to prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by having the same form?

Comment: I think it is clear (s)he means the form $n^2 + 3m^2$ with $gcd(m,n) = 1$.

Comment: If you know Eisenstein integers, this lemma is quite trivial.  Maybe, you can start by showing all prime natural numbers $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ can be (uniquely, in fact) written in the form $x^3+3y^2$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Batominovski, any reference you can point me at?

Comment: Did you mean $x^2+3y^2$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $x^2+3y^2$.  There are many places where you can look up for Eisenstein integers, one being http://ajm.asj-oa.am/263/1/AJMv5i1a4.pdf.